# Add a live background to an Android View (like the Twitter App)

Tags: android, background, android-activity

In the official Twitter Android app, the opening activity (the dashboard) and the Tweets tab activity have a live background/wallpaper (clouds moving, etc).

How do you accomplish that?

Is it as simple as setting your view's background to a live wallpaper drawable?

And then adding `<uses-feature android:name="android.software.live_wallpaper" />` to your manifest?

Comment: I don't know, but I am pissed they took it out of the app before releasing the source :*(

Comment: The timing of my question is funny - the day I ask this question, I get the new Twitter app update and guess what? No moving clouds/bird animations anymore.  I wonder what happened.  The animation possibly could have been a battery drain, but that app was the de facto look of the modern Android application.  Too bad...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's definitely not using a live wallpaper. You can create a custom Drawable or a custom View and draw the animation yourself.

Comment: Thanks Romain - I'll give that a shot.  If I'm successful, I'll post an example.

Answer (score 0):

Adobe AIR? Maybe?
[labs.adobe.com](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/air2/android/)